# Compute integral of a "map" along a given direction

Tags: python, rotation

EDIT: this is for Python!

Im trying to compute an integral of a "map" to produce a line density but I want my integration direction to vary based on the map itself. Here is the idea:

[image]

Now, the test case that I am using is the following picture:

[image]

So I want to integrate along the cross direction of the "plume", and as such my axes are rotated by an angle of around 90 + theta compared to the regular x and y axes, where theta is rotation angle of the plume with respect to the (original) x axis.
I have tried rotating the entire matrix of values using ndimage.rotate and integrate the rotated picture in the normal x and y directions. This does, however, not produce the desired results for the final line density as I lose information regarding the "direction" of the plume (all integrations are done for a northern plume).

I'm sure there must be a way to perform an integration along a specified axis but I can't quite find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please specify language/framework you're trying to use

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do so! Edited the post accordingly, its for Python.

Comment: Do you know the solutions now? I am also struggling to reproduce Beirle et al (Science 2011)! Many thanks if you somehow know the answers now.